# angularjs - adding a controller in the pre-defined module not works

Tags: angularjs

In my `app`, instead of keeping separate `modules`, I am using a generic `module` name as `myApp.controllers` in this module i am injecting to application. later I am adding a new `controller` to the existing `myApp.controllers` but it's not working.

what is wrong here?

here is my code :

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

var appModules = ['myApp.controllers']

var app = angular.module('myApp', [appModules]);

angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.name = "World";

}])
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/19yOmDPUu9Dg5TbIVbTU?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either have:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', appModules);
```

or

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers']);
```

The second parameter is supposed to be an array of `strings` (or `array` of variables containing `strings`), you are passing it a double `array` when you do `[appModules]` as `appModules` is an `array` in itself.

EDIT: updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hQOzV9oPCsEwqU2dUW4c?p=preview

UPDATE:
for the second issue:
you are defining the module twice.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('subController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.son = "Adil";
}]);
```

should be

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
.controller('subController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.son = "Adil";
}]);
```

see updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/xcWdAJuoN3zYKm29nIgY?p=preview

Comment: check here, still i am facing issue, when i add the new controller ( adding one more additionally with new name ) http://plnkr.co/edit/19yOmDPUu9Dg5TbIVbTU?p=preview

Comment: this seems to be the same plunkr, the old one with one controller

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115080/discussion-between-user2024080-and-gaurav5430).

Answer (score 0):

This would work. You will need to inject module name in myapp instead of var `appModules`.

```
var appModules = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);


var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'myApp.controllers' ]);

angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){

 $scope.name = "World";

 }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fixed [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WEP37wAMXF1ktDyc808d?p=preview)

First mistake (then you changed the Plunker):

Changed

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [appModules]);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', appModules);
```

Second mistake:

This is an setter:    `angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])`

This is an getter:    `angular.module('myApp.controllers'`)

You used the setter twice.

One small comment not regarding the issue. Either I don't get what you mean with 'myApp.controllers' or you didn't get the concept of angular right.
What you are holding in your `modules` variable are in fact modules, not controllers.
So if you like to hold your controllers in an array (for whatever reason - I wouldn't recommend this) you can do this like that:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LMGrn7aYSfz9cx6ZGv9v?p=preview)

Comment: the OP is trying to create a module that will have all the controllers registered, so that all controllers can be registered using that single module. similarly we can have separate modules for services and directives.

Comment: ok thanks for clarification. Didn't get this. Maybe because it's a really bad practice in my eyes.

Comment: This is another way for modularizing your code, you would have your controllers in a separate module, services in separate, filters in separate, etc. I have seen a few tutorials advocating this.